# Datatable data at different frequencies

Tags: c#, datatable

My datatable has 19 columns with the first column all filled with timestamps in milliseconds:
18491
18591
18691
...

Randomly in the timestamp column, the time will change from +100 increments to +50 increments:
20291
20341
20391
20441
...

and back again, multiple times.

The other columns have different values of data spread about at different frequencies such as 1 Hz, 5Hz, 10Hz with double.NaN in between the values.

What is the best way to average these columns to 1Hz data while neglecting the NaN cells and creating a new datatable with only 1Hz data and no blanks?
i.e.:

From:
Time Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
18491 4.0 2.2 NaN 1.0 NaN
18591 NaN NaN 1.0 1.0 NaN
18691 NaN 3.2 NaN 2.0 NaN
18791 NaN NaN NaN 3.0 NaN
18891 NaN 4.4 NaN 1.0 NaN
18991 NaN NaN NaN 4.0 NaN
19091 NaN 1.4 6.0 4.0 NaN
19191 NaN NaN NaN 3.0 NaN
19291 NaN 3.2 NaN 2.0 NaN
19341 NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.0
19391 NaN NaN NaN 3.0 NaN
19441 6.0 3.4 NaN NaN 1.0
19491 NaN NaN NaN 2.0 NaN
19541 NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.0
19591 NaN NaN 3.0 4.0 NaN
19641 NaN 5.2 NaN NaN 1.0
19691 NaN NaN NaN 2.0 NaN
19791 NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN
19891 NaN 4.1 NaN 0.0 NaN
19991 NaN NaN NaN 2.0 NaN
20091 NaN 2.2 4.0 1.0 NaN
20191 NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN
20291 NaN 5.1 NaN 1.0 NaN
20391 NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN
20491 5.0 3.3 NaN 2.0 NaN

To:
Time Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
18491 4.0 2.2 NaN 1.0 NaN
19491 6.0 3.21 3.5 2.5 1.5
20491 5.0 3.98 3.5 1.5 2.0

Any help is appreciated, I'm still new to C# and datatables so thank you all in advance!

Comment: Why are your results all rounded to 491?  Is that a hertz?

Comment: If not, then what you probably really want is a clustering algorithm, because what you round to will vary.

Comment: Right, all the timestamps are in milliseconds but the data is recorded at those specific times. This is just an example datatable, other ones have different timestamps that end in some other value.

Really I look at it as 18.491, 19.491, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With Rounded as
(
   Select ROUND(SomeColumn, -3) as RoundedToThousands From SomeTable
)
Select RoundedToThousands, Count(*) from Rounded 
Group By RoundedToThousands
```

You will need to modify the rounding logic to match your requirements for how you decides 491 vs 441 as the round to number.  Probably some combination of floor instead of round, and then + 491.

Comment: But how do I average the corresponding columns into 1Hz data that match the time stamps? Especially with NaN between the recorded values?

Comment: What are you averaging on?  You only have one column.  If I say give me an average of the grades in a class, the result is a single row.  If I say, average the number of grades by age, then I get an average for each age.  Your input only has one column, but your output has multiple rows, so there is no way this is an average.  My point being, what you are describing is very unclear.  Your example for one thing shows only values of *91, yet if you average some values that are 41 and some that are 91, you are bound to get other intermediate values.

Comment: @Freddy For example, the average of 20341 and 20391 in your example would be 20366, but your example shows a result of 20491.  So it appeared from YOUR EXAMPLE, that you actually are ROUNDING to the nearest 491, which is not an average at all.  So maybe a more complete example with maybe ten starting rows, and show exactly what you would want the output to be.

Comment: Thanks for your help Aaron, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I added a better example in my question.